# Azure app service (linux) with ASP.NET Core 8 Web API results in http 403 error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-403, .net-8.0, azure-bicep

For a school project, I'm making a CI/CD pipeline using bicep and github actions.

The bicep file is pretty basic and creates 3 resources.

- an app service
- an server farm
- app insights

```
@description('Specifies the location for resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var envResourceNamePrefix = 'staging-testwebsite'

@description('Deployment name id.')
param deploymentNameId string = '0000000000'

// create azure insights
resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: '${envResourceNamePrefix}-app-insights'
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    publicNetworkAccessForIngestion: 'Enabled'
    publicNetworkAccessForQuery: 'Enabled'
  }
}

var appInsightsKey = appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2023-01-01' = {
  name: '${envResourceNamePrefix}-app-sp'
  location: location
  kind: 'linux'
  sku: {
    name: 'B1'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: '${envResourceNamePrefix}-app'
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    reserved: true
    siteConfig: {
        // alwaysOn: true cant be set for free tier
        linuxFxVersion: 'dotnet|3.1'
    }
  }  
}

output deploymentNameId string = deploymentNameId
output appInsightsInstrumentionKey string = appInsightsKey
output webAppName string = webApp.name
```

Then using a github actions workflow, I'm publishing and deploying my web app to Azure.

This all done successfully, and the pipeline completes without errors, and the code has been deployed to my app service.

However, whenever i go to the site, it returns a `403 forbidden nginx/1.24.0`

The weird thing, is very rarely, it does work and actually lets me call an endpoint.

I have an endpoint called `website-url/test` which just returns `test`. And I've had instances that it actually returns this. But most of the times, when I go to that endpoint in the browser, it gives me a 404.

Within azure, the app service is configured for networking :

- Public network access
  Enabled with no access restrictions

because it should be publicly available, I don't understand why I get a http 403 forbidden error.

The project I am publishing is an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API.

EDIT:
The log files of the app service logstream:

```
2024-03-08T09:52:24.661209363Z: [INFO]  Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-03-08T09:52:27.264971290Z: [INFO]  Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-03-08T09:52:27.303758390Z: [INFO]  Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh     -bindPort 8080 -startupCommand 'php-fpm;'
2024-03-08T09:52:27.513169309Z: [INFO]  Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2024-03-08T09:52:27.513220809Z: [INFO]  Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2024-03-08T09:52:27.540329219Z: [INFO]  Build Operation ID: 7d8f3084-eed3-4166-a5ff-381919ea0532
2024-03-08T09:52:28.951354426Z: [INFO]  Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-03-08T09:52:29.818185526Z: [INFO]  Starting nginx: nginx.
2024-03-08T09:52:30.993719813Z: [ERROR]  [08-Mar-2024 09:52:30] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 82
2024-03-08T09:52:31.021318926Z: [ERROR]  [08-Mar-2024 09:52:31] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Comment: This is really strange, because you are not deploying nginx at all on your code... Have you tried to access from another device and/or network?

Comment: Yes, Tried to acces it from mobile, different web browser, switched wifi and network, and incognito mode. All the same result. 

I figured the Nginx is because it's a linux hosted app service?

Comment: My bad, you are right about the Nginx in the linux hosted app service... Can you check this and see if the issue might be similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76827986/i-deployed-an-application-on-azure-app-services-but-for-some-reason-it-only-giv

Comment: You might be on to something, since the logstream does show somthing about a missing manifest and creating a startup.sh. (See edit in the post for logfiles).

Altough the article in the issue you related to is no longer available, and i'm not really proficient in this, i'm not to sure what my steps are to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Usually, forbidden error occurs when the server got your request but unable accept it to send a response and refuse it. This might be due to the following reasons.

***Need to check below:***

- I could see the error has `"nginx/1.24.0"`, so this one or any `NSG's` might be blocking or restricting the app service to run as expected. Cross verifies if any NSG rules or IP addresses or firewalls are restricting the traffic.
- This kind of issue happens if you have configured any private endpoint which is linked to an app service and then public network access will be enabled.

Refer [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1355758/the-web-app-you-have-attempted-to-reach-has-blocke) for more relevant details on the above point.

- Check your `Startup.cs` file for any other configurations that could be leading to authorization problems. Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76864910/19785512) by @AjayKumar on the same issue.
- You can check all the above information such as Ip blockers, network restrictions clearly by going to your `App service` and check the app service logs under `Monitoring` or also check the `Log Stream` to retrieve more information about errors. Also, you can check under application insights linked to your app service.

*I tried the same code as you and was able to perform the deployment successfully as shown below.*

```bash
@description('Specifies the location for resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var envResourceNamePrefix = 'staging-testwebsite'

@description('Deployment name id.')
param deploymentNameId string = '0000000000'


resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: '${envResourceNamePrefix}-app-insights'
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    publicNetworkAccessForIngestion: 'Enabled'
    publicNetworkAccessForQuery: 'Enabled'
  }
}

var appInsightsKey = appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2023-01-01' = {
  name: '${envResourceNamePrefix}-app-sp'
  location: location
  kind: 'linux'
  sku: {
    name: 'B1'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: '${envResourceNamePrefix}-app'
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    reserved: true
    siteConfig: {
        // alwaysOn: true cant be set for free tier
        linuxFxVersion: 'dotnet|3.1'
    }
  }  
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

*I also checked my app URL which is working as expected.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping both!

In my case, i've set the `linuxFxVersion: 'dotnet|3.1'  wrong, since the application is build in dotnet 8.

I changed it to linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|8.0' and now it all works..

Silly oversight after all I guess